# How is this statement regarding placing balls into bins true?

Tags: probability

Placing n balls into n bins one at a time, chosen uniformally over all bins.

$X_{i}$ the random variable corresponding to the number of balls in the ith bin.

Then $$P[X_{i}=k] \le \frac{1}{k!}$$

I see why that is true, just by writing out using binomial distribution and using basic inequality.

Then my teacher wrote the following which I do not really understand

Let $t=2\log n$ and $\log n \ge e^{3}$

then

$$P[Xi=t]=\frac{1}{(2\log n )!}=\frac{1}{\log n^{\log n}} \le \frac{1}{e^{3\log n}}=\frac{1}{n^{3}}$$

That I dont understand, first of all, in the first part we showed it is less then or equal not equal so im not sure how it follows, secondly I dont see how those expressions in the denominator are equal

Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: We have $P[X_i=t]=0$ whenever $t$ is not an integer.  Also, $(2\log(n))! \neq \log(n^{\log(n)})$.

Comment: @Michael Thats what I thought, I assume he meant less then or equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two "$=$" relations clearly should have been $\leq$ instead.

Given that $t = 2\log n$ and using
the known fact that $P[X_{i}=k] \le \frac{1}{k!},$
and assuming that $2\log n$ is an integer,
simply set $k = t = 2\log n$ and substitute, and you have
$$P[X_{i}=t] \le \frac{1}{(2\log n)!}$$
(substituting $t$ for $k$ in one place, and subsituting the equal quantity 
$2\log n$ for $k$ in the other place).

Note that this implies that $n$ is *not* an integer. (The only case in which $n$ and $2\log n$ both can be integers is when $n=1,$ which is ruled out by the condition $\log n \geq e^3$).

Any factorial $m!$ for $m \geq 1$ has at least 
$\left\lceil\frac m2\right\rceil$ factors that are each at least 
$\left\lceil\frac m2\right\rceil,$ where
the expression $\left\lceil\frac m2\right\rceil$ is $\frac m2$ "rounded up",
that is, $\left\lceil\frac m2\right\rceil \geq \frac m2.$
Therefore for $m \geq 2,$
$$m! \geq \left\lceil\frac m2\right\rceil^{\lceil m/2\rceil}
 \geq \left(\frac m2\right)^{m/2}.$$
This is just as true when $m = 2\log n \geq 2 e^3$ as for any other $m\geq2.$
Therefore  $(2\log n)! \geq (\log n)^{\log n}.$
(The parentheses around $\log n$ are missing in the question; 
that appears to be a mistake.)

Since $\log n \geq e^3 > 1,$ it follows that $(\log n)^r \geq (e^3)^r$
when $r \geq 1,$ including the case where $r = \log n > 1.$
So that gives us 
$(\log n)^{\log n} \geq (e^3)^{\log n} = e^{3\log n}.$

Finally, $e^{3\log n} = (e^{\log n})^3 = n^3.$